# Javascript Safari IOS 10.3.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

When placing an order for a test product at:

https://thenaughtypint.com/products/coaster-2

via safari IOS 10.3.1 and customize the text, the ordered product doesn't show on the cart page unless you refresh the page or hit update then it shows fine.

If I remove the code at the bottom of cart.liquid (Shopify site) it works fine but it doesn't show the custom text on the product in the image on the cart page then.

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery("p:contains('YourDesign')").css("display", "none");
  jQuery(".YourDesign").each(function(i) {
    img_url = $(this).html();
    img_width = $(this).siblings("a").children("img").width();
    jQuery(this).siblings("a").children("img").attr("src", img_url.replace(/&amp;/g, "&"));
    jQuery(this).siblings("a").children("img").width(img_width);
  });
});
```

Comment: The code you've posted runs just once when the page is loaded. If you want to change the page later on, you need to put the code into an event handler that runs in response to the user's action.

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: You've got some code that places an order, right? I assume it uses AJAX to send the order to the server, and gets something back. In the callback function, it needs to add the new product to the DOM. You haven't provided enough details about your HTML or application to be more detailed than that.